# Npgsql Visual Studio Client SSL certificate

Tags: postgresql, ssl, visual-studio-2017, npgsql

There seems to be no option to provide client ssl certificates when creating a new connection for an ADO.NET entity data model on visual studio using Npgsql. I'm not setting it in code, I'm first trying to create the data entity model so code is useless at this point. I can ignore the servers ssl certificate but I can't seem to supply one on my own. Is there a way around this as it is impossible to connect to my postgresql server without an ssl certificate or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

At this time there isn't an option for supplying a client certificate.

Furthermore, if I recall correctly, the Visual Studio extensibility API (DDEX) only allows that dialog box to construct the connection string, but the certificate is a callback that needs to be programmatically set on the connection, outside of the connection string. In other words, there's a good chance supporting this isn't possible, unless a connection string option is added for providing certificates (all this needs to be verified).

Comment: If I remove the SSL requirement on my database to create the model, then switch it back on. Is there a way to modify the connection string to take the SSL certificate? (p.s what an overlook)

Comment: I don't really understand the question - the only way to provide a client certificate is programmatically, there's no way to do that currently via the connection string. FYI this is the very first time anyone's ever asked for this feature, as a general rule people probably use Visual Studio to model and develop against a test/dev database where password (or Kerberos) auth is fine, and when the app is running in production setting the certificate programmatically is OK. That being said, you're welcome to open an issue requesting this on http://github.com/npgsql/npgsq.